# Replace words in a paragraph using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, replaceall

I have a paragraph of some texts. I want to replace some words in that using wildcard.

The below is my Paragraph.

```
      0.7% lower on the prospect of fresh restrictions that would deal a blow to hopes of a swift economic
     recovery.  <Origin Href=\"StoryRef\">urn:newsml:reuters.com:*:nL4N2EC04Z</Origin>\n The 2,000-plus cases reported on Sunday was a shocker ,said Nicholas Mapa, ING
```

In this Para, I want to remove `<Origin Href=\"StoryRef\">urn:newsml:reuters.com:*:nL4N2EC04Z</Origin>\n`
There are multiple paragraphs. But only the uncommon one is  `nL4N2EC04Z`
All other words are common in those paragraphs .

```
<Origin Href=\"StoryRef\">urn:newsml:reuters.com:*:(need_to_use_wild_card_here)</Origin>\n
```

I tried to replace one half.
My code

```
storyRef="<Origin Href=\"StoryRef\">urn:newsml:reuters.com:*:";
storyRef.replace(storyRef," ")
```

But am stuck in replacing other parts.

Comment: Try `\w+?` for your wildcard. If you know how log it is, use `\w{10}`.

Comment: It is error prone to use regex to parse HTML/XML

Comment: have you tried  (<Origin.*<\/Origin>\\n)

Answer (score 0):

It seems encoding problem. Try to use `JSON.stringify` to ensure that characters like `<` and some others does not read decoded.

You can improve Regex too to something like this

```js
storyRef.replace(/<Origin.*Origin>\\n/gm, ' ');
```

This example will start in `<Origin`, get all content between until `Origin>\n`.

```js
const p = JSON.stringify('0.7% lower on the prospect of fresh restrictions that would deal a blow to hopes of a swift economic recovery.  <Origin Href=\"StoryRef\">urn:newsml:reuters.com:*:nL4N2EC04Z</Origin>\n The 2,000-plus cases reported on Sunday was a shocker ,said Nicholas Mapa, ING');
     
const storyRef = JSON.parse(p.replace(/(<Origin.*Origin>\\n)+/gm, ' '));

console.log(storyRef);
```